# Simplify pandas expression

Tags: python, pandas

Not a great question, but here it goes:
I'm doing a very simple calculation combining a couple of columns of a DataFrame, but only if one column has a certain value. The idea is:

```
if df.x==1:
    df.y = df.y - df.a/df.b
```

Now of course loops are slow, so I'm doing this on subsets of the DataFrame, but this gets very verbose very quickly:

```
df.loc[df.x==1, 'y'] = df.loc[df.x==1, 'y'] - df.loc[df.x==1, 'a']/df.loc[df.x==1, 'b']
```

I have a feeling that there is a nicer way of doing this, any ideas?

Comment: won't `df.loc[df.x==1, 'y'] = df['y'] - df['a']/df['b']` just work?

Comment: I think you're right - I somehow thought I had to ensure that all objects on the right hand side were of the same length as the one on the left hand side, but it seems okay to just to it for all objects on the RHS and just write to a subset on the LHS...

Comment: The rhs will align to the index on the lhs, as we use `loc` here it ensures that the correct rows will be assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @EdChum alludes to in his comment, you can just use `.loc` directly.  You can further simplify by using the `-=` notation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'y': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'a': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'b': [2, 2, 2]})

>>>  df
   a  b  x  y
0  1  2  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
2  3  2  3  3

df.loc[df.x==1, 'y'] -= df.a / df.b

>>> df
   a  b  x    y
0  1  2  1  0.5
1  2  2  2  2.0
2  3  2  3  3.0
```